# accessibilityPerformMagicTap not called every time

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have tried `override func accessibilityPerformMagicTap()` both within a particular view controller and within AppDelegate.swift

When it works, it is great. But it does not work in all situations. The function in AppDelegate is called more often than the function in the ViewController, but still not every time the gesture is performed.

Is there anything you can suggest I look into that may be causing the function not to be called in certain situations of my app's runtime when the gesture is performed?

Thank you!

```
override func accessibilityPerformMagicTap() -> Bool {
    print("magic tap performed in app delegate")

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "magicHappened"), object: nil)

    return false
}
```

Comment: Would you mind providing accurate examples of situations in which this function doesn't work, please?

Comment: @XLE_22 after much debugging, I have found that magic tap will only work if there is a currently 'in focus' accessibility element. I wish I could focus on an element without VO reading it out loud, for the purpose of allowing the magic tap to work.

Comment: You can't  focus on an element with no reading out from VoiceOver otherwise how can the user know what he has selected: that's the goal of VoiceOver ⟹ "I describe what you have selected thanks to your gesture". I don't know your specific use case but the magic tap is usually known by the users for answering phone calls and video/audio playbacks. Please, take care of your new potential function that will make these common features ignored when your app is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my testing, the magic tap only works when there is a currently 'in focus' accessibility element of your app.